# How to restore a very large sql text dump file into Postgres 14 using psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a very large sql text dump file that I need to restore to an existing database on a remote machine. THe problem is the text dump file includes roles and has a different owner. I tried to restore it using

```
psql -h localhost -U your_username -d your_database_name -f path/to/your/backup.sql
```

but it also imported the roles and overwritten my postgres owner password. I cannot edit the sql file as it is too large (cannot be opened on notepad++ either). How do I skip importing these roles and change the owner to postgres using command line?

Comment: Ideally don't have the dump in a plain-text file, so that you can pick and choose what you restore (the "custom" format). But, given that you do have a text file, either get a better text editor (something that doesn't try to fit the whole file in RAM) or more RAM or learn to do some search+replace with scripting tools (perl, python).

Comment: You can do the search and replace using a programming language like Go, C#, C++ ...

Comment: Use `pg_dump` rather than `pg_dumpall` to create the dump and use the `-O` and `-x` options.

Comment: There are editors that can handle humongous files. Google it.

Comment: "but it also imported the roles and overwritten my postgres owner password. "  But other than that, it was successful? So then just fix those things, and you are done.

Comment: the dump was done by someone else and cannot be repeated. is it not possible to skip the role creating commands through the psql command itself? i dont want to have to open in a text editor and make changes and save it as another copy as I would still want to keep the original in case i made a mistake . that would mean a total of 400GB of storage use

Comment: It is not possible, `psql` will just run the statements in file as presented to it. You either have to change the statements in the file before you submit it to `psql` or in the database after the statements have been run.

Comment: thanks. i managed to use powershell to remove the create role lines but it did not do it perfectly. i have more lines to remove and to replace the owner name with postgres instead. I received a nice solution from chatgpt on how to create the powershell script but i will need to modify it further. is there a way to open the file partially just to remove some lines in the beginning and save it?